# Nest e2e test : Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I perfome some e2E test in nestJs microservice (using Redis as transporter).
Everything is going well except that the process never end.

This is the message displayed on console

```
Ran all test suites.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Here is the code of my controller

```
import {Body, Controller, HttpCode, Post, Query} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import {Client, ClientProxy, MessagePattern, Transport} from '@nestjs/microservices';
import {AdminDto} from "./admin.dto";
import {Admin} from "./admin.interface";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  /** Useful for test only **/
  @Client({ transport: Transport.REDIS })
  client: ClientProxy;

  @Post()
  @HttpCode(200)
  call(@Query('command') cmd, @Body() data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.client.send<number>({ cmd }, data);
  }
  /** End of test **/

  @MessagePattern({cmd: 'createAdmin'})
  async createClient(adminDto: AdminDto): Promise<Admin> {
    return await this.appService.create(adminDto);
  }
}
```

And this is my app.e2e-soec.ts file, as you can see, I close all connection on afterEach fuction.

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import {Transport} from "@nestjs/microservices";
import {AppModule} from "../src/app.module";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import {connection} from "mongoose";

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let server;
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    server = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();

    app.connectMicroservice({
      transport: Transport.REDIS,
      options: {
        url: 'redis://0.0.0.0:6379',
      },
    });
    await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
    await app.init();
  });
    
  it(`/POST (create admin)`, done => {
    const adminDto = {
      firstName : 'test',
      lastName: 'toto',
      password: '1234',
      email: 'test@toto.fr',
      roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
    };

    return request(server)
        .post('/?command=createAdmin')
        .send(adminDto)
        .end((error, response) => {
          expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
          expect(response.body).toMatchObject({
            _id: expect.any(String),
            firstName: "test",
            lastName: "toto"
          });
          done();
        });
  });

  afterEach(async done => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    await connection.close();
    await app.close();
    done();
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

As Jesse Carter advice, I've added `leaked-handles` to get more clues

Seems it's because of redis

```
tcp handle leaked at one of: 
    at RedisClient.Object.<anonymous>.RedisClient.create_stream (/Users/myUser/project/admin-service/node_modules/redis/index.js:195:31)
tcp stream {
  fd: 38,
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  address: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 54468 },
  serverAddr: null
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It might be late but you have to call the close function from the module variable, like this:

```
afterEach(async done => {
  for (const connection of connections) {
    await connection.close();
  }
  await app.close();
  await module.close(); // <-- this line
  done();
});
```

Thats what worked for me.

Comment: Closing the module solved the problem in our case. Thanks for posting that answer!

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally you might run into an error from Jest indicating that it did not exit properly, eg:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests.
Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

This is usually a sign that there is indeed a problem and shouldn't be ignored. However, taking the advice of running with `--detectOpenHandles` doesn't always give actionable feedback about where the problem lies.

An alternative community package called [leaked-handles](https://github.com/Raynos/leaked-handles) is available which might help track down the culprit. Install this package to your `dev dependencies` for the project that has non-exiting tests and put the code `require('leaked-handles)` at the top of the test files. Observe any output regarding leaks in your test runner. It will often tell you exactly what port or service is still active and preventing the test from closing.

If you capture this output and share it here we will be able to help you with more specifics about what cleanup logic may be missing.

**Side Note:**

I would generally advise that you do module level startup and tear down in the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` lifecycle methods as opposed to doing in between each test. It might not be related to your issues but will make a big difference in how long your test suites take to run

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question with more details

Comment: I face the same issues. After finding the connection for Redis not closing , how do you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue with Redis. Seeing `TCPSERVERWRAP` when using the `--detectOpenHandles` flag with Jest.

As a workaround, you can pass the `--forceExit` flag to Jest.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me becuase of TypeOrm connection is not getting closed after finishing the Test suite. In order to resolve the issue,

**Option 1**

1. Set TypeOrmModuleOption -> **keepConnectionAlive: false**
2. Close the app at the end of the test suite.

   ```
   afterAll(async () => {
       await app.close();
   });
   ```

**Option 2**
Close the connection inside `afterAll()`

```
import { Connection } from "typeorm";
...
...

let app: INestApplication;
let module: TestingModule;
let connection : Connection;

beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(...),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([DomainRepository]),
      ],
      controllers: [DomainController],
      providers: [DomainService]
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    connection =  module.get<Connection>(Connection);
})

afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    await app.close();
});
```

Comment: For the option 2: "Connection" and ".close()" method are deprecated now in TypeORM. One should use "DataSource" and ".destroy()" method instead.